# Are all non-associative (not necessarily associative) finite division rings finite fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quasigroups

According to the Artin–Zorn theorem, any finite alternative division ring is a finite field, but I'm interested in the general non-associative (i.e. not necessarily associative) case. Are there any non-associative finite division rings different from finite fields, or are all non-associative finite division rings finite fields?

Edit: We define a not necessarily associative division ring to be a set $S$ equipped with two binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$ such that

1. $S$ with $+$ is an abelian group
2. $S/\{0\}$ with $\cdot$ is a loop (unital quasigroup)
3. $\cdot$ distributes over $+$.

This comes from the following defintion of a division ring: a set $S$ equipped with two binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$ such that

1. $S$ with $+$ is an abelian group
2. $S/\{0\}$ with $\cdot$ is a group (associative loop)
3. $\cdot$ distributes over $+$.

Comment: What do you even mean by "not-necessarily-associative division ring"? There are several equivalent ways to define inverses in the presence of associativity and without associativity you have to pick one, and the usual one ($a a^{-1} = a^{-1} a = 1$) is pretty useless without associativity! There's no guarantee that $a^{-1}$ is unique and you can't use it to cancel $a$ from a product. So... what's it even good for?

Comment: The way I was thinking it as was a set $S$ with two binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$ such that $\cdot$ distributes over $+$ and that $S$ is an abelian group with respect to $+$ and a loop with respect to $\cdot$. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Whoops, yeah I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the algebra over $\mathbb{F}_3$ with basis (as a vector space over  $\mathbb{F}_3$) the set $\{1,x,x^2\}$ and multiplication given by:
\begin{eqnarray*}
x(x^2)&=&x+2,\\
(x^2)x&=&1+x+x^2,\\
(x^2)(x^2)&=&x.
\end{eqnarray*}

By construction it is finite, has a two-sided identity $1$ and multiplication distributes over addition.  The first two equations demonstrate that it is non-associative.  Also left or right multiplication by any fixed non-zero element is bijective (see proof below).

I fixed the first equation and did a computer search through the $676$ possibilities for the other two.  Of these $14$ came out as having the left and right cancellation property.  One of these was of course $\mathbb{F}_{27}$.  The other $13$ are non-associative, and of them the above algebra seemed like the nicest.

Proof of left and right cancellation:

---

It suffices to prove that left multiplication by any non-zero element is injective, as then it must also be surjective and the algebra will not contain non-zero zero-divisors. Thus right multiplication by any non-zero element would also be injective, hence bijective.

Both $x^3-x^2-x-1$ and $x^3-x-2$ are irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$ as they have no roots in $\mathbb{F}_3$.

Left multiplication by a non-zero $\mathbb{F}_3$-linear combination $\alpha(x)$ of $1$ and $x$ is the same map as left multiplication by $\alpha(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^3-x-2)\cong\mathbb{F}_{27}$ - hence bijective.

Similarly left multiplication by a non-zero $\mathbb{F}_3$-linear combination $\alpha(y)$ of $1$ and $y=x^2$ is the same map as left multiplication by $\alpha(y)$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[y]/(y^3-y^2-y-1)\cong\mathbb{F}_{27}$ - hence bijective.

Thus without loss of generality, if there is a non-zero left zero-divisor, there will be one of the form $\lambda+x\pm x^2$, for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{F}_3$.  Thus it suffices to check that the matrices representing left multiplication by $x\pm x^2$ have no eigenvalues in $\mathbb{F}_3$.  The characteristic polynomials of these matrices are:

$$
\left| \begin{array}{ccc} t&2 &1 \\
2&t+2&1\\
2&1&t
\end{array}\right|
= t^3-t^2-t-1
,\qquad
\left| \begin{array}{ccc} t&1 &1 \\
2&t+1&0\\
1&0&t
\end{array}\right|
=  t^3+t^2+2
.$$

Neither of these cubics have roots in $\mathbb{F}_3$.

---

Answer (score 3):

We provide a family of examples of finite [division algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra), which additionally have a right identity.  This does not answer the revised version of the question which asks for a finite division algebra (other than a finite field) which has a two-sided identity.

On any finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q=p^r$, and $p$ prime, $r>1$, we can define $a\star b= ab^p$.  This is non-commutative ($a\star b\neq b\star a \iff a^{-1}b\notin \mathbb{F}_p$), but has the two-sided cancellation property: $$a\star b=0\implies a=0\,\, {\rm or}\,\, b=0,$$ and has a right identity.

Comment: "This does not answer the revised version of the question which asks for a finite division algebra (other than a finite field) which has a two-sided identity." Lol, I forgot rings could be considered as algebras whose vector space basis is just the set $\{1\}$.

Comment: @MadeleineBirchfield By division algebra,  I meant over the field $\mathbb{F}_p$ generated additively by your unit.  I have added a proof to the other answer, so it now stands independent of computation.  Still slightly unsatisfying that it did not occur conceptually.

Answer (score 1):

Nonassociative division rings with unity are known as *semifields*. They come up in the coordinatization of projective planes. Their study in the finite case started with

Donald Knuth, Finite semifields and projective planes. *J. Algebra* **2** (1965), 182-217.

This published version was based on Knuth's 1963 PhD dissertation.

There is a considerable literature on semifields, but note that the term "semifield" is also used in a conflicting sense in other parts of mathematics as an associative semiring with unity in which every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse. Papers on semifields in the nonassociative sense are generally tagged with the MSC classification 17A35 (Nonassociative division algebras).